# Add symbol between the letter S and any number in a column dataframe

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to add a `-` between letter `S` and any number in a column of a data frame. So, this is an example:

```
VariableA

TRS34
MMH22
GFSR104
GS23
RRTM55
P3
S4
```

My desired output is:

```
VariableA
TRS-34
MMH22
GFSR104
GS-23
RRTM55
P3
S-4
```

I was trying yo use `gsub`:

`gsub('^([a-z])-([0-9]+)$','\\1d\\2',myDF$VariableA)`

but this is not working.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `^([a-z])-([0-9]+)$` regex attempts to match strings that start with a letter, then have a `-` and then one or more digits. This can't work as there are no hyphens in the strings, you want to introduce it into the strings.

You can use

```
gsub('(S)([0-9])', '\\1-\\2', myDF$VariableA)
```

The `(S)([0-9])` regex matches and captures `S` into Group 1 (`\1`) and then any digit is captured into Group 2 (`\2`) and the replacement pattern is a concatenation of group values with a hyphen in between.
If there is only one substitution expected, replace `gsub` with `sub`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glpx8X/1) and the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/6ApCDq).

Other variations:

```r
gsub('(S)(\\d)', '\\1-\\2', myDF$VariableA)             # \d also matches digits
gsub('(?<=S)(?=\\d)', '-', myDF$VariableA, perl=TRUE)   # Lookarounds make backreferences redundant
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version I like using `sub`:

```r
myDF$VariableA <- gsub('S(\\d)', 'S-\\1', myDF$VariableA)
```

This requires using only one capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(myDF$VariableA, 'S(\\d)', 'S-\\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use lookbehinds if you set `perl=TRUE`:

```
> gsub('(?<=S)([0-9]+)', '-\\1', myDF$VariableA, perl=TRUE)
[1] "TRS-34"  "MMH22"   "GFSR104" "GS-23"   "RRTM55"  "P3"      "S-4"    
>
```